# How do I include window as a valid prop with PropTypes?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am trying to define my list of PropTypes for a class component. The component can accept either a regular DOM element or `window` as its prop value. Currently, I have:

```
class FooContainer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        container: PropTypes.oneOfType([
            PropTypes.element,
            PropTypes.instanceOf(Element),
        ]),
    };
    static defaultProps = {
        container: window,
    };
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div />
        );
    }
}
```

However, when the component defaults to using `window` as the container prop, the following error is thrown:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `container` supplied to `FooContainer`.
```

As such, what is the valid PropType to use for property with value of `window`?

Comment: Maybe `PropTypes.instanceof(Window)`?

Comment: @AndrewLi, `Window` is undefined, if i try `window` instead, i get `Failed prop type: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable`. i guess `window` is not instanceable? or doesnt have the `instanceof` method.

Comment: How about `instanceOf(window.constructor)`

Comment: @AndrewLi, there we go :D if you pop that in an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is use `oneOfType` and include an instance of the `window` object's constructor, `Window`:

```
PropTypes.instanceOf(window.constructor)
```

This will allow any `Window` instance as a prop value.

Comment: What about TypeScript? I have this error at `window.constructor` : 
Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => unknown'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): unknown'.ts(2345)